# WedDav folders on Ubuntu Server 18.04.4

Tags: server, kubuntu, apache2, webdav

I have an 18.04.4 Ubuntu server running well on an i5 machine with 8 gb ram. Apache, MariaDB and all doing well and installed the old fashioned way on bare metal. I installed webdav and love what it can do. On the clients we have Mac Users Windows etc.  They are all working fine, read write delete. I can mount the remote shares with ssh just fine.  All permissions.

I have Kubuntu 18.04.4.  In Dolphin I can add the webdav folder easily.

```
webdavs://webdav.msgcnx.com/data/msgcnxFiles
```

I can read, edit and add anything.  BUT I can't delete.[EDIT: I can create and delete folders.  Just not files of any type]  Deleting is working on Mac and Windows. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I had no hits on this question so I will post my workaround.  Seems to be a Kubuntu/Dolphin specific problem([kde forum](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=224&t=151993)).  Nautilus (still in Kubuntu) can read/write/delete just fine. So this will work for now.  Most clients work in Windows or Mac so this is only necessary for a few.

Also had to add a cron job to the server to make NFS happy on all the local/LAN computers.

```
sudo chown walt:walt -R /files/
```

Webmin is running that every minute.

Yes Yes its a hack but works!